# Installing Background Mode shows warning in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-plugins

I am trying to install background Mode in ionic.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode
npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode@4
```

Below is error

> getting below warning
>       ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode
>       $ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-mode@4

and when I use in `Home.ts` file it says as

> pluginWarn @ vendor.js:52024
>       vendor.js:52018 Native: tried calling BackgroundMode.un, but the BackgroundMode plugin is not installed.
>       pluginWarn @ vendor.js:52018
>       vendor.js:52024 Install the BackgroundMode plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode'
>       pluginWarn @ vendor.js:52024
>       vendor.js:1639 ERROR plugin_not_installed

can somebody suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Check your cordova version

```
cordova -v
```

Now cordova version is 9.0.0 then problem will be there.
Referece: 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/backgroundmode-not-installing-cordova-9/160226/4
Now globally  uninstall cordova by following command

```
where cordova // windows users
which cordova //mac users
```

It will give full path of cordova 
Now, 
   npm uninstall -g cordova 
It will remove cordova globally
Now install specific version of cordova here,
   npm install -g cordova@8.0.0
It will install cordova version 8.0.0 
and you can now able to install BackgroundMode plugin. Thank you and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Reverting from Cordova 9.0 back to Cordova 8.0 fixed the issue with background-mode plugin not installed.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@8.0.0
```

Remove the plugin and platform folders and re-build.

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

or with Ionic

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android
```